# How to autogenerate classes with colors from the brightness to the darkness?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm new to SASS and I'm trying to autogenerate classes with specific columns.

For examples I have colors variables:

```
$ccom-grey: (
100: #e7e7e7,
200: #d0d0d0,
400: #bababa,
500: #a4a4a4,
600: #8e8e8e,
800: #797979,
900: #505050
);

$ccom-green: (
100: #6DDD4F,
200: #58D935,
400: #43D41C,
500: #2ECF03,
600: #29BA03,
800: #25A602,
900: #209102
);
```

And method (I'm not sure I made this right):

```
@mixin generate-color-classes($colorName, $color, $hue) {

.#{$colorName}#{$hue}-bg {
background-color: $color !important;
}

.#{$colorName}#{$hue}-border {
border-color: $color !important;
}
}
```

How should I generate colors for every value for example for CCOM-GREY-100 I also want to generate class `.#ccom-grey-100-bg` with color from CCOM-GREY-100. I really don't know how to do this. Maybe someone can help me? Thanks

After applied changed from @ReSedano 
[image]

I'm getting this error:
[image]

EDIT2:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work with nested maps => https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps

So, first of all create a nested map:

```
$colors:(
  ccom-grey: (
    100: #e7e7e7,
    200: #d0d0d0,
    400: #bababa,
    500: #a4a4a4,
    600: #8e8e8e,
    800: #797979,
    900: #505050
  ),
  ccom-green: (
    100: #6DDD4F,
    200: #58D935,
    400: #43D41C,
    500: #2ECF03,
    600: #29BA03,
    800: #25A602,
    900: #209102
  )
);
```

And then you could use double [@each](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each) to iterate over every key/value pair of `$colors`:

```
@each $name, $hues in $colors {
  @each $n, $hex in $hues {
    .#{$name}-#{$n}-bg {
      background-color: $hex !important;
    }

    .#{$name}-#{$n}-border {
      border-color: $hex !important;
    }
  }
}
```

The output is all yours classes:

```
.ccom-grey-100-bg {
  background-color: #e7e7e7 !important;
}

.ccom-grey-100-border {
  border-color: #e7e7e7 !important;
}

.ccom-grey-200-bg {
  background-color: #d0d0d0 !important;
}

.ccom-grey-200-border {
  border-color: #d0d0d0 !important;
}

.ccom-grey-400-bg {
  background-color: #bababa !important;
}

.ccom-grey-400-border {
  border-color: #bababa !important;
}

.ccom-grey-500-bg {
  background-color: #a4a4a4 !important;
}

.ccom-grey-500-border {
  border-color: #a4a4a4 !important;
}

.ccom-grey-600-bg {
  background-color: #8e8e8e !important;
}

.ccom-grey-600-border {
  border-color: #8e8e8e !important;
}

.ccom-grey-800-bg {
  background-color: #797979 !important;
}

.ccom-grey-800-border {
  border-color: #797979 !important;
}

.ccom-grey-900-bg {
  background-color: #505050 !important;
}

.ccom-grey-900-border {
  border-color: #505050 !important;
}

.ccom-green-100-bg {
  background-color: #6DDD4F !important;
}

.ccom-green-100-border {
  border-color: #6DDD4F !important;
}

.ccom-green-200-bg {
  background-color: #58D935 !important;
}

.ccom-green-200-border {
  border-color: #58D935 !important;
}

.ccom-green-400-bg {
  background-color: #43D41C !important;
}

.ccom-green-400-border {
  border-color: #43D41C !important;
}

.ccom-green-500-bg {
  background-color: #2ECF03 !important;
}

.ccom-green-500-border {
  border-color: #2ECF03 !important;
}

.ccom-green-600-bg {
  background-color: #29BA03 !important;
}

.ccom-green-600-border {
  border-color: #29BA03 !important;
}

.ccom-green-800-bg {
  background-color: #25A602 !important;
}

.ccom-green-800-border {
  border-color: #25A602 !important;
}

.ccom-green-900-bg {
  background-color: #209102 !important;
}

.ccom-green-900-border {
  border-color: #209102 !important;
}
```

**EDIT 1**: to get a value of nested map I found here a good solution => https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/deep-getset-maps/ using `map-deep-get` function:

```
@function map-deep-get($map, $keys...) {
    @each $key in $keys {
        $map: map-get($map, $key);
    }
    @return $map;
}
```

and use it:

```
div{
  color: map-deep-get($colors, ccom-green, 100);
}
```

Your output:

```
div {
  color: #6DDD4F;
}
```

Comment: Hi @ReSando! Thank You for Your answer! I did this the way You showed me and I'm gettin weird error. Did I mess up something? *EDIT in question with screenshots

Comment: What's `--{#$color}:#{$value}`? Maybe a variable collision? Really I don't know. Here my code works well: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/a0b15a77d5563d497e1001e59b4096bb

Comment: You had right - I changed map name and it helped. And when my app started where I can find the output css file with generated classes? And also one more question, when I want to use any color for example ccom-grey-100 in any other (not autogenerated) class how can I do this? `$ccom-grey-100` should work if it's element of  the map?

Comment: Normally there is a scss directory and a css directory where the output file is. You have to see your config file to see where is your output file.

Comment: I edited my answer with a solution to take your colors from nested maps. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Thats strange - do I need any other command to generate styles? I don't have generated styles anywhere in project (edit 2 screenshot)

Comment: I think I don't understand you, sorry. Anyway, if you have problems with angular-cli and you want to understand how it works, it is better to ask another question 'cause I don't use Angular, I'm very sorry. :/